# Error al realizar un ggplot de barras horizontales tras publicar una Shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

El caso es que he realizado correctamente una aplicación a través del software R y tras corroborar que localmente todo en la aplicación es correcto, he decidido publicarla en una instancia de shinyapps.io.

Al publicarla en la web, uno de los gráficos que había creado se me cambia y se me visualiza incorrectamente y no consigo encontrar el porqué ya que no ocurre con todos los jugadores, solo con algunos en particular.

Esta es la imagen de como se ve correctamente el gráfico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y de esta manera es como se representa en la herramienta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código perteneciente a esta tabla es el siguiente:

```
  trasp.cor<-cor(trasptotal, method = "pearson")
  df34<-data.frame(row.names(data.frame(sort(trasp.cor[input$seleccionar,], decreasing=T,
  )[2:11])),data.frame(sort(trasp.cor[input$seleccionar,], decreasing=T,
  )[2:11]))
  colnames(df34)<-c("a","b")
  ggplot(df34,aes(reorder(a,-b),b))+ 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue")+
    coord_flip(ylim=c(min(df34$b),1))+
    labs(title="Jugadores más similares",
         x="Jugador", y= "Grado de correlación")+
    geom_text(aes(label = round(b, 1)), nudge_y= 3, color="black")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
})
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que intentes correr el gráfico en tu pc después de hacer `Session > Restart R`  en Rstudio o ejecutar `rm(list = ls())` en la consola. Puede ser que tengas valores en tu Environment que no estén presentes en tu session de Shiny en la web.